# TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined in d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am new to react and Dagre-D3. I converted this Dagre-D3 [demo](http://www.samsarin.com/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/sentence-tokenization.html) to a React component. The code I used is shown below.

```
import React from 'react'
import d3 from 'd3'
import dagreD3 from 'dagre-d3'

export default class EventFlow extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Create the input graph
        var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph()
          .setGraph({})
          .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function() { return {}; });

        // Here we"re setting nodeclass, which is used by our custom drawNodes function below.
        g.setNode(0,  { label: "TOP",       class: "type-TOP" });
        g.setNode(1,  { label: "S",         class: "type-S" });
        g.setNode(2,  { label: "NP",        class: "type-NP" });
        g.setNode(3,  { label: "DT",        class: "type-DT" });
        g.setNode(4,  { label: "This",      class: "type-TK" });
        g.setNode(5,  { label: "VP",        class: "type-VP" });
        g.setNode(6,  { label: "VBZ",       class: "type-VBZ" });
        g.setNode(7,  { label: "is",        class: "type-TK" });
        g.setNode(8,  { label: "NP",        class: "type-NP" });
        g.setNode(9,  { label: "DT",        class: "type-DT" });
        g.setNode(10, { label: "an",        class: "type-TK" });
        g.setNode(11, { label: "NN",        class: "type-NN" });
        g.setNode(12, { label: "example",   class: "type-TK" });
        g.setNode(13, { label: ".",         class: "type-." });
        g.setNode(14, { label: "sentence",  class: "type-TK" });

        g.nodes().forEach(function(v) {
            var node = g.node(v);
            // Round the corners of the nodes
            node.rx = node.ry = 5;
        });

        // Set up edges, no special attributes.
        g.setEdge(3, 4);
        g.setEdge(2, 3);
        g.setEdge(1, 2);
        g.setEdge(6, 7);
        g.setEdge(5, 6);
        g.setEdge(9, 10);
        g.setEdge(8, 9);
        g.setEdge(11,12);
        g.setEdge(8, 11);
        g.setEdge(5, 8);
        g.setEdge(1, 5);
        g.setEdge(13,14);
        g.setEdge(1, 13);
        g.setEdge(0, 1)

        // Create the renderer
        let render = new dagreD3.render();

        // Set up an SVG group so that we can translate the final graph.
        let svg = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nodeTree));
        let svgGroup = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nodeTreeGroup));

        // Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
        render(d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nodeTreeGroup)), g);

        // Center the graph
        let xCenterOffset = (svg.attr("width") - g.graph().width) / 2;
        svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + xCenterOffset + ", 20)");
        svg.attr("height", g.graph().height + 40);
    }

    render() {
        return (<svg id="nodeTree" ref="nodeTree" width="960" height="600"><g ref="nodeTreeGroup"/></svg>);
    }
}
```

but when I run this code snippets in the console am encountered with this error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined`.

I tried to find out the reason. but couldn't. How can I overcome this issue? please someone help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`d3` is `undefined`. Probably because you're not importing it well. From its [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3), if you want to have access to all D3's methods, you should do

`import * as d3 from "d3";`

Comment: It solved that issue. Thanks :) btw it gives another error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeTree' of undefined"

Comment: Your current problem has the same cause: an `undefined` object. From what I can see, your `this.refs` is undefined, probably because you defined your `ref` attributes wrongly. The `ref` attribute takes in a callback function, as [you can see in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: sorry for asking again. I didn't find any thing wrong with ref I defined in the svg. if u don't mind,can u please explain more with my code

Comment: As I said above, check the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

I believe you have to declare your refs some other way